# how to proportionally round to integer values

Tags: predictive-modeling, statistics

I am trying to model student progress. Grades are integer values, but progress predictions are fractional.

For example, I have 10 students who are predicted a grade 6, but the model says they should achieve 6.8

Obviously, I can round this to grade 7 for all students, but it would be more satisfactory to have 8 students predicted 7, and 2 students predicted as 6.

so a couple of questions - is this sort of 'rounding' a thing (and if so does it have a name)?

and more importantly - any thoughts on methods to achieve this proportional rounding (a name I just made up) for the few thousand grades I am modelling.

Comment: With linear regression you can maybe control this by selecting the appropriate family.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a pure regression approach, you could use [ordinal regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_regression):

> In statistics, ordinal regression, also called ordinal classification, is a type of regression analysis used for predicting an ordinal variable, i.e. a variable whose value exists on an arbitrary scale where only the relative ordering between different values is significant. It can be considered an intermediate problem between regression and classification.

This would give you discrete predictions but keeping the ordinal relation among classes (unlike pure multiclass classification).